# What is a book about cooking called?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

What would be the right sentence to use to say that I am reading a book about cooking?

- I am reading a cooking book
- I am reading a cook book

Please explain the reason for the choice.

Comment: Why not "cookbook" (one word)?

Comment: Thats why am asking to learn :)

Comment: Everyone says 'cookbook'; no one says 'cooking book'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*A cooking book* would be an odd thing to say. *Cook-book* (with or without a hyphen, and with or without a space) is fine, and so is *cookery book*.

Comment: I agree, a cooking book seems to imply the book is an ingredient. I would always call such a book a cookery book.

Comment: In American English, *cooking book*, *cook-book* and *cookery book* are virtually unknown; see [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cookbook%2Ccook-book%2Ccookery+book%2C+cooking+book&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Comment: @bib ngram shows *cookbook* really came into being around 1910 in AmE. Till then it was predominantly *cookery book*. (http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=cookbook%2Ccook-book%2Ccookery%20book%2Ccooking%20book&corpus=5&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=1930)

Answer (score 4):

Reading a book about cooking, reading a cookbook, reading a cook book, and reading a cooking book could potentially be four different things:

1. A book about cooking is generally an instructional book or informational book like a textbook, book on the history of cooking, etc. It may have recipes as well, but the focus will be on cooking as a subject.
2. A cookbook is generally a book of recipes. There may be a few other things, but the recipes are the primary focus.
3. A cook book is somewhat awkward, and might want to be avoided, as there's the chance it could be interpreted as a book about cooks rather than cooking or recipes (at the very least it's ambiguous)
4. A cooking book is even more awkward, as it could potentially bring to    mind an image of reading a book that is sitting in a pot, simmering with the stew.

Answer (score 0):

A **book about cooking and includes recipe** can be called **Recipe Book** or **Cookery Book**.

Comment: I've lived in the US as a native speaker of English my entire life, and I've never heard either of these terms used.  UK and other English speaking countries may have different usage patterns, of course, but in the US both of these would sound very awkward.